# SendInput with unicode string not properly sent into UWP app on Windows 10

Tags: windows, uwp, windows-10, sendinput

I have an app that used to send unicode string (not keystroke) thanks to the SendInput api on Windows XP and Windows 7. I tried it on Windows 10 and noticed that if the target app is UWP (like Edge, OneNote, etc...), the Unicode string is not always properly handled. For example, if the app calls SendInput with 'hello' string, then the app shows either 'hello', 'he', or even nothing.
Thanks for advices

Here is the code, based on Qt integration:

```
  QString text;
  ...
  int i = 0;
  while (i < result.length())
  {
    ...
    // Check if some char needs to be filtered out or converted
    ...
    INPUT Input;
    Input.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
    Input.ki.time = 0;
    Input.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;
    Input.ki.wVk = 0;
    Input.ki.wScan = text.mid(i, 1).utf16()[0];
    Input.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_UNICODE;

    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
    Input.ki.dwFlags |= KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
    SendInput(1, &Input, sizeof(INPUT));
    i++;
  }
```

The Unicode string is sent char by char to filter or convert any char that cannot be displayed.

Comment: Hi, please post the code of your app you're having problems with.

Answer (score 0):

UWP Windows are not 'normal' ones, they are built directly on top of COM, so **user32** functions like sendinput will not work as expected.

If you want to support some kind of Cross-App communications, please check out [AppServices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/launch-resume/how-to-create-and-consume-an-app-service) and well as the samples provided by Stefan Wick [over at his blog](https://stefanwick.com/2018/04/06/uwp-with-desktop-extension-part-1/).

Comment: Thanks Xeorge. The purpose here is to act like an input method. I know the best way would be to develop a TSF module but its quite complex and there's not so much documentation. (even the blog of @EricBrown seems disable from Microsoft blog site). More over, the sandboxed behaviour of UWP app is applied the same way to the TSF module the app is loading, so it's tough to get access to resource on the system beneath in such configuration. SendInput is much easy to implement, that's why I'm trying to get it work.